# searchable linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

everyone

I am working on an RPG game as a class project.
A `linked list`is used for the inventory.
I try to add a search function since I want the user to be able to sell inventory.

The ideal is that `searchItem(string name)` takes the given item name and goes through the list finding the name-matched item, then return address of the item. However, when the function called, the IDE throws a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, adress0x44)` error.

I guess it doesn't return the right address but with my current ability, I can't figure out the solution.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Inventory.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "Item.hpp"
using namespace std;
class Inventory{
private:
    struct Inven{
        Item item;
        struct Inven *next = nullptr;
    };

    Inven *head;

public:
    Inventory();
    ~Inventory();

    void appandItem(Item obj);
    void insertItem(Item obj);
    void deleteItem(string name, int qt);
    void displayInventory();
    Item* searchItem(string name);
};
```

Inventory.cpp 
I only posted searchItem function because others work fine

```
Item* Inventory::searchItem(string name){
    //  to go through the inventory
    Inven *itemPtr = nullptr;
    //  to point to the previous item
    Inven * previousItem = nullptr;

    //  if the invnetory is empty, nothing happands
    if(!head)
        return nullptr;

    //  determine if the first item is the one.
    if(head->item.getName() == name){
        //  if so, return the address of item
        return &itemPtr->item;

    }else{
        //  Initialize itemPtr to head of inventory
        itemPtr = head;

        //  skip all items whose name is not match
        while (itemPtr != nullptr && itemPtr->item.getName() != name){
            previousItem = itemPtr;
            itemPtr = itemPtr->next;
        }
        //  return the address found
        if (itemPtr){
            return &itemPtr->item;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

here is the code where searchItem is called, can not access to getSellValue() which is defined in `Item` class

```
#include "Shop.hpp"

//  sell inventory for gold
int Shop::sell(Inventory inventory, string itemName, int qt){
    this->goldEarned = inventory.searchItem(itemName)->getSellValue() * qt;
    inventory.deleteItem(itemName, qt);
    return this->goldEarned;
}
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger. First it can be used to catch crashes like yours, and help you locate where in your code it happens. When you catch the crash you can also examine the values of all involved variables, to make sure all of them are what they're supposed to be. And you could also use the debugger to step through your code (before the crash, obviously) statement by statement, and also examine variables and their values.

Comment: A probable hint though: There are cases when `searchItem` will return `nullptr` (for example if the item isn't found, or there are no items). Think about what happens if you attempt to dereference that null pointer, as you *unconditionally* do in the `sell` function.

Comment: Why did you `#include <list>`, yet didn't use [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?  If you used `std::list`, a lot of that code wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you, I was dumb.  if the head is the match one, I should return &head->item.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your reply. I just learned linked list a week ago. Our professor gives extra credit if we don't use STL list.

Comment: *"the IDE throws"* -- no, it's your program that throws. The IDE just shows you what was thrown (part of its job as an *integrated* development environment). *On one hand, this is a small wording issue. On the other hand, since it's your program that throws, you should be able to identify which line triggers it, not just which function. Which brings us back to using the debugger.*

Comment: @ZhihanL -- Well ask yourself, and maybe even the teacher this:  Are you developing an RPG game, or trying to maintain a linked list?  If it's the former, then use the components that are already developed, such as `std::list`.  If it's the latter, then the assignment should only be about maintaining / creating a linked list.  Even if you used `std::list`, you still have to write the code to use it properly -- the code won't magically write itself.